# is chocolate an allowable after noon?

Tags: vinaya

i recently went to a meeting with some bhikkhus, and they served the monks a small dish with butter slices and little chocolate squares... i think it was dark chocolate if that matters.

So anyway, i was suprised to see it and was wondering other views on this.

and the underlying point to the question... i am obviously looking for loop holes for a snack-ish type thing before bed.

Comment: ADENDUM-  i can also note that a vegan raw foodist that i knew made chocolate... it was one of the few treats allowable for his diet... so i would imagine the right kind of chocolate might have been prepared under the right conditions. What might they be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cocoa is a powder made from the seed from the cocoa tree. Since seeds fall into the category of food, it would not be allowed outside of the morning hours.

Chocolate also has narcotic properties, so could potentially be considered a medicine. [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chocolate#Health_effects) it may reduce cholesterol and ease diarrhea symptoms, so for people suffering from either of those ailments, it could be used at any time and kept for life, provided that was the reason for use.

It is quite surprising to hear that otherwise strict monks are using it as a refreshment in the evening; I think they consider the natural fatigue and perhaps even hunger in the evening to constitute "sickness" that chocolate "cures". It is quite clear, however, that the Buddha allowed only fruit and vegetable juice for that purpose and using the oil found in much chocolate for this purpose is an abuse. Sugar might be okay, since it is technically dehydrated juice, but that is still a bit of a stretch.

Comment: I actually though of ground up seed and realized it was definitely solid food. i dont specifically remember seeing them actually eating a piece... but it was on the plate. one monk passed his to the crowd so maybe they didnt eat it. I did though... haha.

Answer (score 0):

For monks it is permissible to have [Chathu Madura](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/dhammamedicine/PmCrk3bO7qA/CwJ_-zuFYREJ) after noon. I am not sure if the chocolate counts. The correct way to prepare it is in the attachment in the discussion.

May be what you saw as Chocolate would have been [Jaggery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaggery). Depending on the type it might have a chocolate like appearance.

Any way if you meditate intensively looking at the hunger sensation or food craving it will pass away without the need to eat later.

Comment: maybe they consider it an allowable substitute if it is the right preparation, it was definitely chocolate.